# how to simulate modem disconnection to change ip address programatically

Tags: networking, ip-address, modem, dynamic-ip

Whenever I disconnect a modem and than reconnect it, my ip address changes. How does one replicate this process (the ip change caused by disconnection and subsequent reconnection) programatically?

Comment: You could ask the DCHP server for a new address?  You may have to delete/remove/flush current lease info from your DHCP client.

Comment: Thank you. If you have time, could you provide an example?